# Failed to load JNI shared library "D:eclipse\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"

Tags: eclipse

My laptop contains windows 8, 64 bit OS, I have installed jdk7 in c:programFiles, it has jre7 too, and I want to run eclipse, I am getting error as Failed to load JNI shared library "D:eclipse\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll".

Please do help me ...

Answer (score 0):

add debug flag to your eclipse.ini
-D C:....\java.exe would solve the problem